# Get both parent and child text with Xpath (HtmlXPathSelector)

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping a website, and I need to get the numerical values from this HTMLdocument:

```
<td>
<span style=" color: red; font-weight: bold;"> 1.950</span>
</td>
<td> 3.400</td>
```

I need to extract both 1.950 and 3.400, but I can't figure out how to do it, when the one value is only in a , but the other one has a span as well. Is there a general way to get both the parent and the child of the path? I am using the `scrapy` framework with the `HtmlXPathSelector`. I can use the path `/td/text()` for one, and `/td/span/text()` for the other, but I need to do it in one query. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with : `/td//text()` to select every text node that are descendants of a `td`

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two ways to solve the issue.

With Xpath

> following-sibling::node()

and the other is to iterate all tds (but this could be nasty)

I will give you an example with Xpath

```
span_text = hxs.select("/td/span/text()")
next = span_text.select('following-sibling::node()') #you should get 3.400 (or with this idea :P)
```

if you have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
  <td> 
    <span style=" color: red; font-weight: bold;">1.950</span> 
  </td>
  <td>3.400</td>
</root>
```

and you execute this xpath expression :

```
//td/following-sibling::node()
```

you will get **3.400**

[this is a good place to test xpath](http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

`.select("string()").extract()`

It will extract all text without any html tags